# uploading app files on already existing Github repository

Tags: javascript, github, web-applications, electron, svelte

I made an app with `Svelte Electron` recently and unable to upload the app in this folder: https://github.com/daisykumar/tema-8

Is there a way I can do it? What file sizes do I need to reduce?

Comment: The link does not point to a folder but to a github repositoy. Please explain in detail how you 'upload' and what. Do want to make a release and upload the compiled app as an asset?

Comment: The folder name is Svelte Electron and I'm unable to upload it in this repository. I want to upload the complied app as one of the folders in this repository.

Comment: If it is in this folder on your machine, should git automatically track it? Is the name of the folder maybe listed in your *.gitignore*?

Comment: This seems to a general misunderstanding of git and github. We do not *upload* files to the repository. We create changesets and commit them. Github is not a dropbox or cloud storage. I strongly recommend looking for a git tutorial.

Comment: If you want to upload a built app, then you should go to the release tab, create a new release and upload the zipped app or the executable there. Just give it a version number and pull the file from the explorer (or finder) on the drop area.